# Denwer процессы

Tags: denwer

Какие процессы в командной строке запускает Denwer при запуске?

Просто я хочу, чтобы он запускался при автозапуске, а смотреть на черное окошко мне как то не нравится.

Пытался рыться в файлах, но ничего не разобрал.

Помогите пожалуйста.

P.S. настройки Denwera стандартные, ничего не менял. Версия старая с PHP 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

server\denwer\scripts\init.d\mysql.pl собственно вот код запуска MySql

В любом случае это окошко будет.
Ну а заставить его при загрузке системы загружаться, просто прописать путь к файлу **run.exe**

```
#!perl -w
# +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# | ─цхэЄы№ьхэёъшщ эрсюЁ Web-ЁрчЁрсюЄўшър                                   |
# | ┬хЁёш : ─хэтхЁ-3 2010-11-07                                             |
# +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# | Copyright (C) 2001-2010 ─ьшЄЁшщ ╩юЄхЁют.                                |
# +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# | ─рээ√щ Їрщы  ты хЄё  ўрёЄ№■ ъюьяыхъёр яЁюуЁрьь "─хэтхЁ-3". ┬√ эх ьюцхЄх |
# | шёяюы№чютрЄ№  хую т ъюььхЁўхёъшї  Ўхы ї.  ═шъръшх фЁєушх юуЁрэшўхэш  эх |
# | эръырф√тр■Єё .  ┼ёыш т√ їюЄшЄх тэхёЄш шчьхэхэш  т шёїюфэ√щ ъюф,  ртЄюЁ√ |
# | сєфєЄ Ёрф√ яюыєўшЄ№ юЄ трё ъюььхэЄрЁшш ш чрьхўрэш . ╧Ёш Єэющ ЁрсюЄ√!    |
# +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# | ─юьр°э   ёЄЁрэшЎр: http://denwer.ru                                     |
# | ╩юэЄръЄ√: http://forum.dklab.ru/denwer                                  |
# +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+

package Starters::Mysql;
BEGIN { unshift @INC, "../lib"; }

use Tools;
use Installer;
use StartManager;

# Seconds to wait mysql stop while restart is active.
my $timeout = 5;

# Base MySQL dir.
my $basedir = $CNF{mysql_dir};
die "  Could not find $basedir\n" if !-d $basedir;

# MySQL exe name.
my $exe = "$basedir\\bin\\$CNF{mysql_exe}";

# MySQL shutdown utility.

# Config.
my $config = fsgrep { /^my.cnf$/i } $basedir;
die "  Could not find my.cnf in $basedir\n" if !$config || !-f $config;

# MySQL port.
my $port = 3306;
my $conf = readBinFile($config) or die "  Could not read $config\n";
if ($conf =~ /^\s* port \s* = \s* (\d+)/mix) {
  $port = $1;
}

StartManager::action 
  $ARGV[0],
  PATH => [
  ],
  start => sub {
    ###
    ### START.
    ###
    print "Запускаем MySQL...\n";

    if(chechSocketIfRunning($port)) {
      print "  MySQL уже запущен.\n";
    } else {
      if(!-f $exe) {
        print "  Не удается найти $exe.\n";
      } else {
        # Patch the 2-year bug in MySQL. :-(
        if (($ENV{OS}||"") !~ /nt/i && $exe =~ /mysql5/) {
            getComOutput(getToolExePath("mysql5018_9x_patch.exe") . " " . $exe);
        }
        # Run the server.
        my $cmd = join " ", (
          "start $exe",
          ($exe=~/mysqld-max/? ("--defaults-file=$config") : ()),
          "--user=root",
          "--standalone",
#          "--init-connect=\"insert into mysql.test set test=current_timestamp()\"",
          "--basedir=$basedir",
          "--character-sets-dir=$basedir/share/charsets",
          ($CNF{mysql_args}||""),
        );
        system $cmd;
        print "  Готово.\n";
      }
    }

  },
  stop => sub {
    ###
    ### STOP.
    ###
    print "Завершаем работу MySQL...\n";

    my @ps = Tools::searchForProcesses($exe);
    if(@ps) {
      foreach my $ps (@ps) {
        my $r = kill 2, $ps->{pid};
      }
      sleep(1);
      # If some processes haven't finished, do it again
      # with more cruel signal.
      @ps = Tools::searchForProcesses($exe);
      foreach my $ps (@ps) {
        my $r = kill 9, $ps->{pid};
        print "  Process $ps->{exe} (PID=$ps->{pid}) killed with signal 9\n";
      }
      print "  Готово.\n";
    } else {
      print "  MySQL не запущен.\n";
    }
  },
  _middle => sub {
    ###
    ### MIDDLE: after "start" of "restart".
    ###
    my $tm = time();
    if(chechSocketIfRunning($port)) {
      print "Ожидаем завершения MySQL (максимум $timeout секунд) ";
      while(time() - $tm < $timeout) {
        print ". ";
        if(!chechSocketIfRunning($port)) {
          print "\n";
          return;
        }
        sleep(1);
      }
      print "\n";
      print "  Не удается дождаться завершения!\n";
    }

  },
;

return 1 if caller;
```

Comment: Собственно, этот файл я нашел, но мне нужны пути к файлам запуска разных программ по отдельности (MySQL, Apache и т.д.)

Comment: > my $exe = "$basedir\\bin\\$CNF{mysql_exe}";

>server\usr\local  

так сложно найти... ай яй яй...